# one div with 100% width and two fixed divs in one line

Tags: css

I need three divs in one line.

One is size 200px, second 300px and last div should be what's left.

Why is my last div in a new row?

```
<div style="float: left; width: 200px; background: #223355">a</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 300px; background: #223344">b</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 100%; background: #334455">c</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AS others have said 100% is 100% of page width.. but I disagree with user who says it can't be done with 'plain' CSS

```
<div style="float: left; width: 200px; background: #223355">a</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 300px; background: #223344">b</div>
<div style="overflow: hidden; background: #334455">c</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because by specifying `width: 100%`, you've told the third `div` to fill the entire width of the page, not just what's left over. By adding a couple of wrapper `div`s, you can get something like this:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 100%">
   <div style="margin-left: 500px; background: #334455">c</div>
</div>

<div style="float: left; width: 500px; margin-left: -100%">
   <div style="width: 300px; float: left; background: #223355">a</div>
   <div style="width: 200px; float: right; background: #223344">b</div>
</div>
```

Which should render the way you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you just have to remove the float:left; on the last div for it to work?

Comment: yes, but any text in last "column" will wrap below first two if you don't also add `overflow: hidden;` - depends on the use case really

Answer (score 0):

Because you've set it to 100% width. A relative width, such as your percentage, applies to the width of the PARENT element. So if your container for those 3 divs was 600px, then you'd end up with your third div taking 100% of 600px, not the "leftover" space that the other two elements have used up.

What you want cannot be accomplished with plain CSS. You'd need to calculate the remaining space via Javascript and set the third div's width that way, or make it fixed-width as well.