# CSS: How to set several div's in one line with 100% width?

Tags: css, html, css-float

The similar question was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749507/one-div-with-100-width-and-two-fixed-divs-in-one-line) but my divs haven't fix size at all. I need follow stucture:

```
<div style="float:left;"></div>
<div style="float:left;"></div> <!-- this div should be what's left after the first and third divs -->
<div style="float:right;"></div>
```

I have tried to set  `overflow:hidden;` for the second div but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve with the combination of `white-space` & `display:inline-block` like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.child{
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* for IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* for IE7*/
    min-width:100px;
    min-height:50px;
    margin-right:10px;
    background:red;
    white-space:normal;
}
.parent{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/QdvFp/1/

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunetely, this is not what I really wanted. I solved my problem, but thanks to your script I filled the gap in my knowlages:)